# How to change a link in a navbar to active on the layout depending on the view that the @RenderBody displays?

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net, bootstrap-5

I'm making an ASP.NET web app and I'm using MVC. Naturally, the app has a shared layout in which a different view is displayed. All the views, including the layout use bootstrap, and in my layout I'm displaying a navbar in which when you click on one of the items it redirects you to it's corresponding view. Usually in bootstrap when you add the 'active' class to an nav-item and the 'aria-current' attribute, when you click on a link and the page opens, the link stays active letting you know what is the page you currently are.

[Here's an example of what i'm talking about](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sjsaQ.gif)

The problem I have is that in ASP.NET apparently 'aria-current' attribute is not recognized cause when I add it, it doesn't make any difference and all the items in the navbar stay active.

[This is my navbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EEnC1.gif)

Also, when generating the layout, ASP.NET uses html helpers like @Html.ActionLink instead of the <a> tag. Nevertheless, I've tried both to add the 'aria-current' attribute, to the helper and a <a> tag, and the result is still the same:

```
<ul class="navbar-nav flex-grow-1">
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                @Html.ActionLink("Licencias", "Index", "Licencias", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "nav-link active", @aria_current = "page" })
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                @Html.ActionLink("Productos", "Index", "Productos", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "nav-link active", @aria_current = "page" })
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                @Html.ActionLink("Vendedores", "Index", "Vendedores", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "nav-link active", @aria_current = "page" })
                            </li>
</ul>
```

```
<ul class="navbar-nav flex-grow-1">
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a aria-current="page" class="nav-link active" href="/Licencias">Licencias</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a aria-current="page" class="nav-link active" href="/Productos">Productos</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a aria-current="page" class="nav-link active" href="/Vendedores">Vendedores</a>
                            </li>
</ul>
```

Is there a way to achieve the active link in a current view maybe with javascript? For example with an 'if(@RenderBody() == "Specific view")' or idk, something else?